# Are any palm leaves of puranas preserved and available today?

Tags: puranas, manuscripts

Are there any palm leaves of hindu scriptures (especially puranas) available for us to read today?

Also I am interested to know whether any ashramas or certain brahmin families have the oral tradition till today (which is very unlikely to happen).

Comment: Why? I have seen more than one man chant the entire Katha Upanishad from memory.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda.What I mean is that it is more unlikely for someone to chant a *purana* out of memory or having an oral tradition of chanting puranas. That is not the case with vedas and upanishads.

Answer (score 1):

I heard most of the valuable sources are outside India.

[Thanjavur Saraswathi Mahal Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saraswathi_Mahal_Library) is one among several known depositories.

Comment: Though intersting I had highligted or specified puranas in my question. Are you sure Thanjavur Saraswati Mahal Library have manuscripts of puranas and if so what purana it is??. Well, it is difficult to completely answer this question, I asked this out of curiosity. Mentioning all these things would completely answer my question.

Comment: There is a reference to MCC in the last line; .After paper printing became common there is no need to keep puranas on palmaira leaves.  Only most valuable personal records were kept for a few common peoples generations, more in royal households

Comment: "After paper printing became common there is no need to keep puranas on palmaira leaves." Even there is no need to burn those  palmaira of puranas after paper printing became common if  I am not wrong. So, where are those last palmaira leaves of puranas is my question.

Comment: Preservation requires chemicals.against termites, vermin. So they may last only a few centuries.